# Границы агрегатов в ddd

Tags: entity, ddd, aggregate

Собственно вопрос заключается в определении границ агрегата.

Представим, что существует сущность упаковка, в упаковку входят какие-то ресурсы. Сама по себе упаковка может быть создана в отдельном разделе и при ее создании мы добавляем в нее ресурсы. Вроде все понятно, упаковка является агрегатом, ресурс упаковки является entity. Но есть отдельный раздел для отгрузки, отгружать мы можем несколько упаковок в рамках одного документа для отгрузки. Так же, при этом в рамках создания нового документа для отгрузки мы можем не только выбирать уже созданные упаковки, но и создавать новые. Более того, по идее все это должно сохраняться в рамках одной транзакции, следовательно получается, что документ на отгрузку является агрегатом, а упаковки в нем entity. Но, вроде как, агрегаты не должны содержать в себе другие агрегаты и должны хранить только ссылки на них по id. Получается вроде как, мы должны вытаскивать уже несколько агрегатов, в рамках казалось бы одного.

Все таки как лучше поступать в подобных случаях? Эрик Эванс писал про ограниченные контексты, м.б. это агрегаты в разных bounded context?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Агрегата в другом агрегате конечно быть не может.

Бывает, что первый объект *содержит* второй; и бывает, что первый объект *ссылается* на второй.

Как отличить? Непросто. Отличие не формальное — *содержит* или *ссылается* зависит от предметной области и её требований.

В одной предметной области колёса окажутся частью автомобиля, и тогда автомобиль с колёсами — это агрегат, колёса — это сущности, а автомобиль — корневая сущность.

Но в другой выясниться, что и колёса и автомобиль требуют отдельного учёта, и здесь сущности-колёса будут содержать ссылку на сущность-автомобиль.

Как это часто бывает в DDD, чтобы разобраться, надо смотреть на сценарии использования (use cases) или пользовательские истории (user story). Если во всех сценариях сущности встречаются только вместе, они образуют агрегат. Наверняка одна из них обладает особым положением, поскольку через неё можно получить все остальные. Её называют *корнем агрегата*.

Именно агрегаты возвращают репозитории. Если упаковка это агрегат, в программе появится хранилище (репозиторий) упаковок, которое сможет загрузить упаковку по её идентификатору.

Но как быть в случае, если агрегаты вроде как пытаются стать частью другого агрегата? Если упаковка бывает без документа, значит, это самостоятельный агрегат.

Чтобы их связать, мы переходим на уровень выше — к *службам* (сервисам). Сервисы это классы, которые олицетворяют процессы в объектно-ориентированной программе. В отличие от сущностей, у них нет состояния. Их методы отражают отдельные шаги многошаговых процессов. И именно они умеют связывать агрегаты, вызывая методы репозиториев.

В вашей программе может быть служба отгрузки, скажем, `ShippingService`, которая может увязывать документы и упаковки. Если речь идёт о ссылке, а не о содержании, агрегаты хранят идентификаторы друг друга. Документ хранит список идентификаторов упаковок, а упаковка — идентификатор документа.

Репозитории могут содержать методы загрузки, опирающиеся на ссылки. Скажем, репозиторий упаковок может предоставить метод загрузки всех упаковок по идентификатору документа.

**UPDATE**

Дополнение для ответа на вопрос из комментария. Поговорим об уровнях приложения. Классическая трёхзвенная модель предполагает наличие уровней 1) представления, 2( предметной области и 3) доступа к данным. Эванс внёс в неё два изменения. Уровень доступа к данным он назвал *инфраструктурным уровнем*, и добавил между представлением и предметной областью четвёртый *прикладной уровень*.

С этим уровнем есть серьёзная проблема, потому что его назначение не очевидно. Я думаю, это происходит потом, что он имеет смысл только в крупных системах, где уровень предметной области начинает разрастаться за счёт разнообразных служб.

Посмотрим на перевод книги Эванса, стр. 109:

> **А вот отличить СЛУЖБЫ операционного уровня от уровня предметной области
>   (модели) бывает труднее**. Операционный уровень отвечает за то, чтобы отдать приказ об извещении клиента. А уровень модели определяет, достигнут ли порог - правда, эта задача не требует отдельной СЛУЖБЫ, а скорее, входит в полномочия объекта "банковский счет". Та же самая банковская программа, возможно, занимается и переводом денежных средств. Если сконструировать СЛУЖБУ, отвечающую за подведение дебета и кредита в процессе перевода, то она будет принадлежать уровню предметной области. Перевод денег - это смысловой элемент банковского дела, а его реализация - это фундаментальная операция предметной области. В технических же службах икакие понятия прикладной модели вообще не должны упоминаться.
>
> Многие СЛУЖБЫ уровней модели и прикладных операций строятся на основе совокупностей ОБЪЕКТОВ-СУЩIIОСТЕЙ и ОБЪЕКТОВ-ЗНАЧЕНИЙ. Они ведут себя как сценарии, которые МОБИЛИЗУЮТ потенциал предметной области на выполнение чего-то полезного. Сами СУЩНОСТИ и ЗНАЧЕНИЯ часто бывают слишком мелкомасштабными, чтобы
>   дать пользователю удобный доступ к возможностям уровня предметной области. Можно
>   заметить, что грань между уровнями предметной области и прикладных операций очень
>   тонка. **Например, если банковская программа умеет преобразовывать и экспортировать все наши финансовые транзакции в файл электронной таблицы (чтобы мы могли его читать и анализировать), то СЛУЖБА такого экспорта относится к уровню прикладных операций.** В предметной области банковского дела никаких "форматов файлов" нет, да и логика прикладной модели здесь тоже не используется.

Я выделил важные части. Моё предложение — в начале разработки не создавать прикладной (операционный уровень вообще). Бизнес-сценарии, которым для работы хватает только сущностей, объектов-значений, регламентов и репозиториев — реализовывать в слое предметной области. Если речь заходит о форматах файлов, дескрипторах окон, заголовках запроса HTTP — делать эти службы частью презентации.

Делать в виде классов, а не виде интерфейсов, который надо реализовать. Здесь интерфейсы не нужны и только усложняют работу. Уровень презентации видит уровень предметной области непосредственно — это просто зависимость проекта от проекта, так что вы при желании может создавать класс служб и сущностей непосредственно, хотя удобнее пользоваться контейнерами IoC из-за сложных конструкторов.

Интерфейсы нужны только для служб инфраструктурного уровня, потому что там нужно инвертировать зависимость. Классически зависимости между уровнями идут верху вниз, но если делать так, то при любой смене инфраструктуры (базы данных, сервиса отправки SMS или электронных писем) нам придётся менять уровни выше — предметной области, прикладной и представления.

Именно поэтому сервис отправки писем или репозиторий присутствует в предметной области в виде интерфейсов, а реализуется в инфраструктурном уровне.

Из вашего комментария я понял, что в вашем случае речь идёт о службе предметной области. Просто сделайте её в виде класса и вызывайте его методы из уровня предметной области, не создавая дополнительных интерфейсов.

Comment: Спасибо, а скажите, служба о которой вы говорите, это будет служба предметной области или служба прикладного уровня? Вроде как, раз она будет использовать репозитории для 2-х агрегатов и иметь какой то свой сценарий, то по идее она должна быть службой прикладного уровня и ее реализация должна быть где то в Application Layer. Интерфейс такой службы лучше объявлять на доменном уровне?

Comment: @АлександрКубит Дописал ответ. В комментарии было бы трудно всё это записать.

Comment: Супер, спасибо, все стало намного понятнее! Я выделил ваш ответ в качестве принятого. Как я понял, в предметной области сущности выражены в виде объектов, у которых есть какие-то действия, если действия не имеют какой-то четкой принадлежности к объектам - создают службу предметной области. А скажите, такие действия, как изменение свойств объекта, например метод ChangeName - ответственность самого объекта, а сохранение изменений в БД - ответственностью репозитория, но все эти действия должны где-то происходить. Это может происходить прямо контроллере или стоит создавать какую-то обертку?

Comment: @АлександрКубит. Для начала можно делать прямо в контролере. Контролер может работать с репозиториями и/или службами. Альтернатива — спрятать всё это в службы прикладного уровня, но в простом проекте методы этих служб будут из одной или двух строк. Такое писать немного лениво. Я бы начинал с простых решений в лоб.

Comment: Благодарю еще раз =)